# LINQ to SQL passing object as parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq-to-sql

To select something with LINQ to SQL this is what we normally do:

```
        DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var value = from employee in context.Employees
                               orderby employee.Salary descending
                               select employee;
```

What if i have like 30 table and i want to write this once in a method and only pass parameters to the function to call some table like this:

```
    public void select_function(Parameter1,Parameter2)
{
    DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var value = from Parameter1 in context.Parameter2
                               orderby Parameter1.Salary descending
                               select Parameter1;
}
```

is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GetTable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220(v=vs.110).aspx) generic method of LINQ to SQL Data Context object. And pass an expression for sorting:

```
public void select_function<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> orderBy)
    where T : class
{
    DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var value = context.GetTable<T>().OrderByDescending(orderBy);
}
```

Usage:

```
select_function((Employee e) => e.Salary)
```

Though you simply can do

```
var value = context.GetTable<Employee>().OrderByDescending(e => e.Salary);
```

without creating any methods